# Set variable depending on MySQL row

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, if-statement

I have a MySQL table that has various entries, some with video links, and some without.  Let's call this row "vid" for now.  I would like, if the row has a link (or any text at all), to set the link equal to the `$pc162v` variable, and if the row has no content for "vid" to set the variable to be blank.

Here's the variable declaration:

```
$pc162v = "";
$v162 = '<center><embed width="420" height="236" src="'.$pc162v.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></center><hr>';
```

Further down in the code, all under an "if" statement:

```
} else {   
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if ($row[7] != "") {
           $pc162vid = $row[7];
        }
        else {
           $vidspot162 = '';
        }
```

The area for the video, even though the PHP is being pointed to the correct row, is blank.  Any help/ideas is appreciated!

Comment: use empty() function to test:if (!empty($row[7])).if you didn't get the answer, var_dump() your row to see if there is any link for the rows or not...

Comment: @1linecode I tried the empty() function as you suggested, and also changed the else code to `else if (empty($row[7]))` but it still shows a blank white section where the video should be.  Also, the var_dump() returned that that row 7 is correct.

Comment: I said if (!empty($row[7])), did you type it right?

Comment: @1linecode Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Yes I did.  I changed the if statement to `if (!empty($row[7]))` and the else section to `else if (empty($row[7]))`.

Comment: no ,the else part must remain unchanged:if (!empty($row[7])) {
           $pc162vid = $row[7];
        }
        else {
           $vidspot162 = '';
        }

Comment: @1linecode Still doesn't seem to work that way either.